# Spring Boot JUnit: How to test if an Autowired field was executed on a void method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I'm trying to figure out how to test if a field is executed when a void method is called. The field that I want to test is a repo/dao Autowired object in a Service class.

```java
@Service 
public class ObjectServiceImpl implement Object Service { 
    @Autowired
    private ObjectRepository objRepo;
    
    private void publishObject(Object obj) {
        objRepo.save(obj); 
    }
}
```

What I want to test is if ObjectRepository used save() when publishObject was called.

PS: the project that I'm working on, the repo being used is an import from a dependency. Also, I'm using JUnit4.

Answer (score 1):

For checking a call of nested dependency usually, you must use `verify()` which is verifies interaction happened:

...

```
  verify(objRepo).save(obj);
```

...